# I installed node,but couldn't use npm

Tags: npm

whether I use .pkg from nodejs.com or brew install node, the node can be successfully installed but not the npm.

`WineHouse:~ yj$ node -v
v4.2.1
WineHouse:~ yj$ npm
-bash: npm: command not found
WineHouse:~ yj$ brew install npm
Warning: node-4.2.1 already installed`

Comment: can you execute npm like this `/usr/local/bin/npm` from terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the solution provided in the gist: [Fixing npm On Mac OS X for Homebrew Users](https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689)

Comment: when I rm /usr/local/bin/npm, it reports`rm: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory`,